# How to rectify my Java exception overflow: index 3 of 3 out of bounds

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, overflow

I am running into an overflow exception. This is a homework assignment; I am not looking for direct answers as that will not help me learn. This assignment is for my Artificial Intelligence class. We are solving the n-puzzle problem using best-first and A* algorithms.

I have a 2D array that represents my game board. there are 8 tiles in total with one blank space. Those who are unfamiliar with n-puzzle. The point is to go from a starting configuration of tiles to the goal configuration by moving the blank tile shifting the other 8 pieces around. So far in this assignment, I am implementing the movement of the blank pieces swapping the blank with the upper, left, right, or closest down tile. I also have my functionality to display the board. I have all my directional movements implemented as well.

I tried declaring a temp 2d array and used the built-in function `Arrays.copyOf(board, board.length)`. When compiling it complained about being passed a 2d array.  I am just not sure how I am going out of bounds with my checks. Also if the array was updated then 'b' would be found at (i= 0, j = 1), adding one to j puts me at the edge of the array. This leads me to believe that I need to copy my 2d array before making more changes. If the array did not actually update 'b' would be on my edge, then I tried moving it right out of bounds. That makes sense to me, but it is showing the array made changes in my output.

I know this is a low-level question. I just can't wrap my head around how to copy arrays in Java, Thanks kindly. My reference right now is "Thinking in Java 4th edition." By Bruce Eckel

Below you will find my main code flow of execution, my moveBlankLeft/Right functions implemented, and the overflow exception produced from running the code.

```
       public static void main(String[] args)
        {
          bestFirst game = new bestFirst( );
          game.displayBoard( );
          game.moveBlankLeft(game.moves, game.defheight, game.defwidth);
          game.displayBoard( );
          game.moveBlankRight(game.moves, game.defwidth, game.defheight);
          game.displayBoard( );
        }
```

```
    int moveBlankLeft(int moves, int defwidth, int defheight)
    {
        moves = moves + 1;
        for(int i = 0; i < defheight; i++) 
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < defwidth; j++)
            {
                if((i < defheight && j < defwidth && i >= 0 && j >= 
                0)&&board[i][j]=='b')
                {
                    char temp = board[i][j - 1]; 
                    board[i][j] = temp;
                    board[i][j - 1] = 'b';
                }
            }
         }
          System.out.println(" Total moves in solving: " +moves);
          return 0;
    }
```

```
    int moveBlankRight(int moves, int defwidth, int defheight)
    {
        moves = moves + 1;
        for(int i = 0; i < defheight; i++) 
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < defwidth; j++)
            {
                if((i < defheight && j < defwidth && i >= 0 && j >= 
                0)&&board[i][j]=='b')
                {
                      char temp = board[i][j + 1]; <-- culprit line...
                      board[i][j] = temp;
                      board[i][j + 1] = 'b';
                }
             }
         }
         System.out.println(" Total moves in solving: " +moves);
         return 0;
     }
```

```
Welcome to the best-first n-puzzle challenge solver.
4 5 b
6 1 8        = initial board
7 3 2
 Total moves in solving: 1
4 b 5
6 1 8        = board after shiftBlankLeft(...)
7 3 2
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 out of bounds for length 3
        at bestFirst.moveBlankRight(best-first.java:83)
        at bestFirst.main(best-first.java:161)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant code (not a screenshot of the code), and have a go at formatting your text to be more concise and readable, and you will be far more likely to get an answer.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I will do so now.

Comment: The issue itself is caused by this line `board[i][j + 1];`, because j only has 3 values at index 0, 1 and 2 (remember an array is 0 based), however, you attempt to use j + 1 which with give an index of 3 on the last loop, which is out of bounds. To solve the issue don't use `j + 1`, or stop your `for` loop one cycle earlier by adding `-1` to the end condition like so `for(int j = 0' j < defWidth-1; j++){...}`

Comment: From the Javadoc, an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is "Thrown to indicate that an array has been accessed with an illegal index. The index is either negative or greater than or equal to the size of the array."

Comment: So, I understand why the exceptions get thrown. I know if you overrun or underflow this is very bad, or by accessing illegal indices. My confusion is we called moveBlankLeft( ) in the output you can see 'b' and 5 have been swapped. Then I call moveBlankRight. I instruct the loop to stop when 'b' is found. In this case it should be at (i=0, j = 1)  due to my moveBlankLeft call. This would make my [j+1] swap with the element at location (i=0, j = 2). I will try stopping early to account for a possible off by one as suggested. I appreciate the feedback so far.

Comment: So, the stopping short did indeed fix the issue. My math was obviously off I am just not sure why. Is it how the matrix is indexed that j needs cut short.  On paper it made sense and the way I implemented the moveBlank.. functions, Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `moveBlankRight` method you should replace your implementation with :

```
if(j== defwidth-1){
    char temp= bord[i+1][0];
    board[i+1][0]='b';
    board[i][j]=temp;
}
else{
    char temp = board[i][j + 1]; 
    board[i][j] = temp;
    board[i][j + 1] = 'b';
}
```

Like that the output will be :

```
Welcome to the best-first n-puzzle challenge solver.
4 5 b
6 1 8        = initial board
7 3 2
 // move right of b
4 5 6
b 1 8        = board after shiftBlankRight
7 3 2
```

**You should also add the condition**  `if(i==defheight-1)`

Comment: Thank, you for the advice. I actually was just doing those suggestions after realizing my mistake. I realize now, I was only wanting one move per call. I was actually performing swaps until the condition was no longer true. I ended up just returning after my swap. Before I perform the swap, I did a check for ensuring the move I am trying to make is still in bounds of the array as you lastly suggested.